# How to update app content downloading data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm about to build an app in which there's an image giving information about weekly events that needs to be updated every week. I cannot update the app every week on the apple store and compel the user to update so often the app, so i was thinking to update automatically the app. I saw an app doing this: it update the content every time the user wanted to look at the need-to-be-updated content AND if he was connected to the internet. If he was online the content displayed would be the last one downloaded. How they could do this this? The only thing i could saw on the app is that when it was downloading the updated content it displayed the the typical wheel (http://spie.org/images/global/SearchWheel_Frame1.gif).

I'm using a sqllite database to store data. In fact, i have to update some strings of data inside the database...

Comment: I'm not clear on what part of the process is causing a problem for you.

Comment: understanding how to do it. I'm using objective for a few month and i don't know so many thing yet... :)